# Game for negotiations

Tags: game-theory

For a while I've been bouncing around an idea for a game to be used in negotiations, with a quantitative voting element. The basic idea goes like this: there is a list of things each side of the negotiation wants (e.g. in a peace negotation, this might be a list of towns). Each side gets 100 points. Then the two sides each secretly write down how many points they're willing to bid for each of those things. Then both sides reveal what they wrote down, and the highest bidder for each thing gets the thing they bid on. The idea is that some things are worth more to one side than the other, so they will hopefully bid over their opponent for the things they want more than their oppenent, and vice versa.

Is there already a game like this floating around? I'd like to read about it.

Comment: I would hesitate to call this "voting".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very much like a [Colonel Blotto game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blotto_game), except there the cities are ordered and the players can only assign points in a decreasing sequence.

Simultaneous multi-unit auctions with a budget constraint may also be relevant.